# jquery focus command doesn't work from chrome command line

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

If I have a text page as described below. The call to  `$("#target").focus();`  in the `$()` section in the header works just fine. I can also bind that command to events in a more realistic page.

However, if I open the chrome console and type  `$("#target").focus();`  it does not change focus. If I run `$("#target").val("something");` it changes the value on the screen, but it does not work with focus.

Obviously this isn't a critical problem, but I am really curious why this happens. Anyone have an idea?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
         $("#target").focus();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

 <body>
   <input id="target" type="text">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You will realize that when clicking on the Chrome console, it will steal focus from any input or textarea control on the current page, and vice versa. That's because the Chrome console actually is implemented using the same HTML controls as any other HTML page, just with special properties which, for instance, prevent Chrome from inspecting the Chrome console recursively.

When you type a command in the Chrome console, i.e. in the input control that is part of the Chrome console, it will keep the focus. The Chrome engineers might have chosen to implement it differently, but in most cases the user will want to continue typing in the Chrome console after firing a command, so no command will release focus from the console.

Comment: If you click on the page's tab so the chrome window is active (when using Windows), the element you tried to focus() from the console should now have the focus. I had the same problem, and found that it does transfer focus within the page, but it simply doesn't show since you're technically in a different window.

Comment: @asifrc Not on my Mac 10.8.2 in Chrome 24.0.x.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't sure about that, but it holds true for Windows in my experience (updated my previous comment).

Comment: This is completely amazing! I just spent like, tons of minutes raging over .focus() not working... because I was testing it in the console. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of possible way is: unfocus / blur your control. Scroll it out of View. Enter the Command to focus in the Chrome Console. If then the Website will scroll up to your Control you can be sure that the Focus Method works.

Answer (score 0):

kind of hackish but works...

try to wrap your highlight code with `setTimeout :D` and before the timer expire click on the web page.

```
ele2 = $('#input')
setTimeout(function(){ele2.focus()},4000);
```