# jQuery focus not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yg49k/

The following code works fine in FireFox but doesn't work in the latest version of Chrome.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="one" placeholder="Type two chars" />
<input type="text" id="two" placeholder="It should focus here" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#one").on("input", function() {
    if($("#one").val().length == 2) { $("#two").focus(); }
});
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Why are you passing 4 arguments to `on` method? You don't have to.

Comment: which version? in 29 it works fine.

Comment: Kinda hacky but: http://jsfiddle.net/yg49k/1/ works now for me.

Comment: Looks like Google fixed the issue, as my jsFiddle link works fine now.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Seems like a bug in Chrome. Sometimes it is too fast to execute events properly;)

Found a workaround http://jsfiddle.net/Rd2rZ/

```
$("#one").on("input", function() {
    if($("#one").val().length == 2) { 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#two").focus();
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

Use `setTimeout` with a minimal delay. It will slow down Chrome and make it work.

Comment: Works perfectly and doesn't compromise the otherwise very useful `on("input...`

Comment: ya, it's simple even no need to set any delay for the timeout

Comment: Yes, very useful event that replaces a use of a bunch of other events. However it is not supported in IE < 9. Use `onpropertychange` event for old IEs.

Comment: @roasted - you're right, I've removed `, 1` and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @roasted Actually there is no difference to set 0 or 1 because different browsers cannot register timeouts less then some amount of ms. This value may vary from 4 up to 20 ms on mobile browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341803/difference-between-settimeoutfn-0-and-settimeoutfn-1

Comment: @claustrofob ya exactly, that's why i said there is no need to set a timeout duration, this save 2 bytes :)  `setTimeout(function(){
            $("#two").focus();
        });`   But spec said duration is required, so.. BTW forgot to upvote this.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#defer's `_.defer` is also possible instead of setTimeout with a delay of 0; works for me.

Comment: great tip! note that this won't work from the console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783585/jquery-focus-command-doesnt-work-from-chrome-command-line?rq=1

Comment: I've found several functions in side events that were seeming to be ignored, added a timeout wrapper to them and they all work. I never would have figured this work around out on my own, Thank you kindly.

Comment: I had to use 600 before it started working on Firefox and Chrome properly, possibly as a result of other JavaScript code / Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
$("#one").on("keyup paste",function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if($(this).val().length == 2) { $("#two").focus(); }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yg49k/2/)

And the same for the `#five` handler.

The [`oninput`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event seems to have the same behaviour as [`onkeypress`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp).

Comment: Does the `on("keyup paste...` method have any downsides in comparison to `on("input...`? I've found it to be reliable (other than when using `focus()` apparently...)

Comment: sorry misread comment. Like i said the downside would be that on blurred element will not fired this handler compare to oninput

Comment: Fair enough. I've noticed if you keep the key pressed down it ignores the function whereas `input` does not.

Comment: test with keypress then. But be aware, onkeypress is not fired by basckspace in chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#one").keydown(function(){
   if($(this).val().length==2)
   {
      $("#two").focus();
   }
});
```

Comment: keydown is bad for retrieve the current (expected) value of input

Answer (score 0):

```html
$("#one").on("input", function() {
    if($("#one").val().length == 2) { $("#two")[0].focus(); }
});
```

Try this!

Comment: This question was posted in 2013, and was actually a bug in Chrome, as per the accepted answer. There's nothing wrong with the JS in the question.

Answer (score -5):

I got the same problem and got it fixed using the following code:
You should also have a name attribute for your input to get this working.

```
$("#one").on("input", null, null, function() {  
   if($("#one").val().length == 2) {  
       setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="one"]').focus() }, 3000);  
   }  
});
```

Hope this helps someone who did not get it working using the other suggestions.