# $(window).focus() not executed properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus, onblur

I want to track clicks on AdSense elements on my page. To achieve that I put the focus on the window object and if it loses focus, I check if the mouse was in the area of the AdSense iFrame. Then i put the focus back on the window again.

This works. But in Chrome it works only once. So if I click on an adSense ad (opening in a new tab) and then I click on another one, the event doesn't fire anymore.

If I execute $(window).focus() in the console, the onBlur event fires again - but the $(window).focus() executed from within my code doesn't show any effect. I tried it with a Timeout too, without success.

Any ideas?

```
trackElements("#contentAdSense, #fallbackAdSense, #sidebarAdSense");

function trackElements (elementsToTrack) 
{
  var isOverElement = false;

  $(window).focus();

  $(elementsToTrack).mouseenter(function(e){
      isOverElement = e.currentTarget.id;
  });

  $(elementsToTrack).mouseleave(function(e){
       isOverElement = false;
  });

  $(window).blur(function(e){
      windowLostBlur();
  });

  function windowLostBlur () 
  {
      if (isOverElement) 
      {
          console.log(isOverElement);
          $(window).focus();
      }
  };
```

};

Simplified version: https://jsfiddle.net/327skdns/2/

Comment: can you please create a fiddle so that we can check in chrome ?

Comment: here is a simplified version -> https://jsfiddle.net/327skdns/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented Chrome bug: [jQuery focus not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384464/jquery-focus-not-working-in-chrome)

You need to wrap your `focus()` call with a setTimeout:

```js
trackElements("#contentAdSense, #fallbackAdSense, #sidebarAdSense");

function trackElements (elementsToTrack) 
{
    var isOverElement = false;

    $(window).focus();

    $(elementsToTrack).mouseenter(function(e){
      isOverElement = e.currentTarget.id;
    });

    $(elementsToTrack).mouseleave(function(e){
       isOverElement = false;
    });

    $(window).blur(function(e){
      windowLostBlur();
    });

    function windowLostBlur () 
    {
      if (isOverElement) 
      {
          console.log(isOverElement);
          setTimeout( function(){ $(window).focus(); }, 50 );
      }
    };
}
```