# How to trigger Angular blur event from browser console?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser-console

I have some inputs that I'm trying fill using a [Chrome snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets). The inputs that are  bound to the component model using `[(ngModel)]="myProperty"` work great. Two of the inputs, however, only update the component model on `blur` (I want one-way template to model binding, which [does not appear to exist](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-way-in)).

For example: `<input id="myId" (blur)="blurs = blurs + 1">`

The following script enters the text just fine but does not trigger the blur, and therefore does not update the model:

```
document.querySelector('#myId').select();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'some text');
document.getElementById("myId").focus();
document.getElementById("myId").blur();
```

[Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wydaje)

I've tried adding a `tabindex` with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783585/jquery-focus-command-doesnt-work-from-chrome-command-line and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096436/document-getelementbyidid-focus-is-not-working-for-firefox-or-chrome

Comment: @yurzui [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096938/7355697) to that second question you posted works great, but only for the element that receives focus _last_. I've tried experimenting with multiple `setTimeout` calls with different timeouts and have had no luck.